# Multisite media library uploads broken images

Tags: multisite, images, uploads, media

I am having an issue with one of my sub-sites media library. All it uploads are broken images. It loads fine locally but for some reason it gives me the error

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://mjstokes.com/victoria/files/2017/02/model6-150x150.jpg"

Locally all uploads goes into my wp-content/uploads path, but as hosted live they go into my files folder. I have already contact my hosting company and they were unable to assist me. Please if there is someone out there who knows of a possible solution please share it me me asap. Thanks!

**Note: The images are present and the file permissions are set to 750 with owner/group 776 774.**

Comment: check your media options "uploading files" under settings -> media

Comment: I don't have that option